# How to write in where clause

Tags: oracle, case

How I can write this code under the `where` clause as a `case` statement?

```
IF trim$(ps_status) <> "" AND NOT isnull(ps_status) THEN 
SELECT CASE ps_status
CASE 'O'
     p_con.pipeline_tx_status = 'O'
CASE 'MFT'
    p_con.pipeline_tx_status = 'MFT'
CASE 'IS'
    p_con.pipeline_tx_status = 'IS'
CASE 'CNF'

    (p_con.pipeline_tx_status in ('CNF') OR  (p_con.pipeline_tx_status in('OI','ICF','C') AND NVL(CONSOL.ACCOUNTING_STATUS,'O') NOT IN ('O'))) 
CASE 'OI'
    p_con.pipeline_tx_status = 'OI'
CASE 'ICF'
    p_con.pipeline_tx_status = 'ICF'
CASE 'C'
    p_con.pipeline_tx_status = 'C'
END SELECT
END IF
```

Comment: You may need to write it with some boolean logic: `where (ps_status = 'O' and ... ) or (... ) ...`

Comment: Or something like `where p_con.pipeline_tx_status = case ps_status when blah then blah etc end`. I didn't really understand your `case` logic though.

Comment: Is this in PL/SQL, or just regular SQL?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll try the suggested steps. IT's a regular SQL.

Comment: I can successfully write the SQL using below code:   
  Select  pipeline_tx_status from pipeline, Consol
  
  Where pipeline.pipeline_tx_status = case UPPER('&ps_status') when 'O' then 'O' 
  WHEN 'MFT' then 'MFT'
  WHEN 'IS'  then 'IS'
  WHEN ('CNF' or ('OI','ICF','C')  then 'CNF'
    End;    But i'm unable to fit this condition under when clause for 'CNF' :(p_con.pipeline_tx_status in ('CNF') OR  (p_con.pipeline_tx_status in('OI','ICF','C') AND NVL(CONSOL.ACCOUNTING_STATUS,'O') NOT IN ('O'))) getting an error missing right parenthesis. please suggest!!